# Dask cluter with workers on different networks

Tags: ssh, dask, dask-distributed

I want to create a cluster using two (or more) laptops connected to different networks. I'm trying `dask-scheduler` and `dask-worker` but it works only if the two machines are connected to che same network.

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything special, except that the machines need to agree on how to address each other: either they will have unique DNS names (unlikely) or fixed IP addresses. You will need to make sure that dask's ports (which you can choose on the command line or config) are open via whatever bridge/route you have between the networks. I'm not sure how you would achieve it with temporary IP (which is more typical for a laptop on wifi).

Note that the client and workers need to be able to initiate contact to the scheduler, and workers need to be able to initiate contact between themselves. It is also best to have the client be able to contact the workers directly.